# How to represent a bus ride in linear programming?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Hi I work as a programmer at a bus company and I need to implement a ride initialization request. I think it might be a linear programming problem but I'm not sure and I ask for some help :)

A passenger sends my server a request to initialize a bus ride.

The request includes the different entities for the ride. For example a request might be :

```
Request = [2 Adults, 3 Children, 1 Dog, 2 Bikes]
```

My server knows what are the different tickets the passenger has. 
Each ticket has a cost (the price the passenger bought it with) and a list of entities it enables a ride for.

For example, a passenger might possess :

```
Ticket1- cost 10, enables [1 Adult, 1 Bike]
Ticket2- cost 20, enables [1 Child]
Ticket3- cost 10, enables [1 Adult, 1 Dog]
```

I would love some help designing an algorithm that finds the optimal collection of tickets to use for the ride (optimal being the cheapest combination), or return error if the ride isn't feasible.

I think this could be represented as a linear programming problem and then I can just use the simplex algorithm to find the optimal solution. But I'm not sure how to do it... please help me I'm not much of a math expert :/

Thank you!

Comment: so in your example you need to minimize cost = 10x+20y+10z subject to x,y,z>=0 (and integers) 1x+1z>=2, y>=3,z>=1, and x>=2 (conditions for each type of rider). That does look like a linear programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some R code that may be used as a template for your problem.

```
library(lpSolveAPI)

solve_request <- function(request, available_tickets) {
    lprec <- make.lp(0, ncol=3) # decision variables: how many tickets of type 1, 2 or 3 
    set.type(lprec, columns=seq(1,3), type="integer") # the decision variables are integers, there are no half tickets
    set.objfn(lprec, obj=c(10, 20, 10)) # objective: minimize costs of tickets

    # first type of constraints: no more tickets than available
    add.constraint(lprec, xt=c(1,0,0), type="<=", rhs=available_tickets["t1"])
    add.constraint(lprec, xt=c(0,1,0), type="<=", rhs=available_tickets["t2"])
    add.constraint(lprec, xt=c(0,0,1), type="<=", rhs=available_tickets["t3"])

    # second type of constraint: choosen ticket must meet request
    add.constraint(lprec, xt=c(1,0,1), type=">=", rhs=request["adults"])
    add.constraint(lprec, xt=c(0,1,0), type=">=", rhs=request["children"])
    add.constraint(lprec, xt=c(0,0,1), type=">=", rhs=request["dogs"])
    add.constraint(lprec, xt=c(1,0,1), type=">=", rhs=request["bikes"])

    solve(lprec)
    return(setNames(get.variables(lprec), c("t1", "t2", "t3")))
}

solve_request(request=c(adults=2, children=3, dogs=1, bikes=2), available_tickets=c(t1=10, t2=10, t3=10))
```

It returns

```
t1 t2 t3 
 1  3  1
```